# What does the hyphen (dash) mean for a Twig block like in {% block body -%}?

Tags: twig

When generating a CRUD in a Symfony2 application with Doctrine commands, generated Twig template content is defined within a Twig block this way:

```
{% block body -%}

{% endblock %}
```

What does the hyphen (dash) in `-%}` mean? It works fine without the hyphen and I could not find anything similar in the Twig documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minus In twig block definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634412/minus-in-twig-block-definition)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

A hyphen (or dash) at the end of a Twig block means to trim trailing whitespace, at the beginning, leading whitespace. Both means... both.

See the [Whitespace Control section of the docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control); their example:

```
{% set value = 'no spaces' %}
{#- No leading/trailing whitespace -#}
{%- if true -%}
    {{- value -}}
{%- endif -%}
{# output 'no spaces' #}

<li>
    {{ value }}    </li>
{# outputs '<li>\n    no spaces    </li>' #}

<li>
    {{- value }}    </li>
{# outputs '<li>no spaces    </li>' #}

<li>
    {{~ value }}    </li>
{# outputs '<li>\no spaces    </li>' #}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it must be hidden somewhere in the documentation and I only knew the `spaceless` tag.
And googling it wasn't easy as "twig block hyphen" couldn't find this piece of information.

Comment: Thanks to you now something useful comes up when you google it.

Comment: I searched for "twig bracket bracket hyphen"

Comment: I searched for "twig dash" I got this question as a first result although there is no single keyword `dash` here

Comment: I searched for "twig percent dash" :D Thank you all for the answers!